# How to use h1 to h6 within header, section, article, etc.. in html5?

Tags: html, seo, semantic-markup, html-heading

In xhtml 1.0 *hn* (h1 to h6) must represent document structure, like chapters in a book, and they all descend from the `body`.
In html5 there are `section`, `article`, `header`, `hgroup`, and it seems that *hn* tags descend from one of these tags, and then are not relative to the body element.
like

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>My personal homepage</h1>
<section id="resume">
<header>
<h1>My resumre</h1>
<p>A brief description of my skills</p>
</header>
<!-- bla bla bla -->
</section>
</body>
```

In xhtml 1.0 I would have done:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>My personal homepage</h1>
<div id="resume">
<h2>My resumre</h2>
<p>A brief description of my skills</p>
<!-- bla bla bla -->
</div>
</body>
```

Does it make sense? Or should I follow the same rules as in xhtml 1.0 and disregard section, header, etc... and make hn tags relative to the body elements?

Advises and answers concerning semantics and SEO are the most valuable for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best SEO is to have good content, simple as that! Semantically what you have illustrated here is fine. What is new in HTML5 is that containers like `<footer>`, `<header>`, `<section>` and `<article>` have their own internal structure, as it were. So the outline of your first example would be:

1. My personal homepage
   1.  My resume

If you were to change the markup to this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>My personal homepage</h1>
    <h2>Introduction</h2>
    <p id="intro">...</p>
    <h2>About me</h2>
    <section id="resume">
      <header>
        <h1>My resume</h1>
        <h2>Overview</h2>
      </header>
      <p>...</p>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

The outline would be:

1. My personal homepage
   1.  Introduction
   2.  About me
       1.  My resume
           1.  Overview

See section 4.4.11 of the draft for an explanation. [Geoffrey Sneddon](http://gsnedders.html5.org/outliner/) has made the [HTML 5 Outliner](http://gsnedders.com/) tool for checking the outline of a page.

Comment: Totally agree about content, but content is best surrounded with good semantics :) THank you for your answer and the tool you provided.

Comment: Agreed; good semantics are as important. Glad to see you picked up on my cheek too! With that in mind, it's worth remembering that Hixie works on the spec *at* Google. I would imagine that Google have already been working on this. Regarding SEO, to quote Jeremy Keith; "If you are thinking in terms of SEO, you are doing it wrong."

Answer (score -1):

Semantically, what you're doing is fine. Maybe the section should be an article.

SEO is probably ok but I couldn't say for certain.